# A method of TableView that's only called the very first time the view is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a master view (UITableView) with two properties that I want to be set only the first time the view is shown (that is; only when the application starts), but not when the view is shown again later on runtime (e.g. when a push-segue drags it on again etc.)

How is this possible? Maybe there's something I've missed?

Thanks in advance. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do it in `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` on your `AppDelegate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `dispatch_once` in a corresponding view controller's method `viewDidAppear:`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        ... your code to be executed only once ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Great answer, and I got it quick! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set it in the `init` method of the class.

Then, if the class is shown again, `viewWillAppear` will be called, so you can set the property back to the value you want.

Another option is to play with the methods `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`